# PLSQL Procudure (Oracle) Comparing a variable in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

This is driving me crazy. I want to do simple comparison of a column and a variable but it just doesn't work. The following line always counts all of the tuples while I only need those as conditioned by the where clause.

```
 SELECT count(*) INTO cnt from class where class.fid = fid;
```

It looks sooooo simple but I've been working on this for hours. The complete sql proc is

The big confusing thing is that if I replace fid with some hard coded ID (like 105) it gives a correct answer), but when I use fid it just doesn't work any more and returns count of all classes. For some reason, always class.fid = fid. When I use >, < or <>, 0 count is returned!

```
create or replace PROCEDURE pro_report2
AS
CURSOR c_dept IS select deptid, dname from department;
TYPE cur_typ IS REF CURSOR;
c1 cur_typ;
query_str1 VARCHAR2(200);
fid faculty.fid%type := 102;
fname faculty.fname%type;
cnt NUMBER;

BEGIN
    FOR dept_row in c_dept LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Dept.Name: ' || dept_row.dname);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Faculty Name' || chr(9)|| chr(9) || '0 Class' || chr(9) || chr(9) || '1 Class' || chr(9) || chr(9) || '2 Classes' || chr(9) || '>2 Classes');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
        --find all faculty in this department
        query_str1 := 'select fid, fname from faculty where faculty.deptid = ' || to_char(dept_row.deptid);
        open c1 for query_str1;
        LOOP
            FETCH c1 into fid, fname;
            exit when c1%notfound;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(fname);
            SELECT count(*) INTO cnt from class where class.fid = fid;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(to_char(cnt) || '    ' || to_char(fid));
        END LOOP;
        -- Spaces between departments
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(chr(10));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(chr(10));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you need to rename or prefix your local variable `fid` as it unfortunately matches the column name in the table you are querying. The SQL engine is simply comparing `fid = fid` for each row, which will always be true (excepting nulls, but that's another story). Plus, it's harder to read your code when you have variables named the same as a column.

In PL/SQL there tends to be a convention to prefix local variables with a `l_` (for local) so it's clear what the purpose is. However, any name other than a column name will suffice. Try:

```
l_fid faculty.fid%type := 102;
```

And then...

```
SELECT count(*) INTO cnt from class where class.fid = l_fid;
```

(Plus other appropriate replacements.)

Comment: Thank you! That was a horrible mistake and it costed me a lot of work. It works now! OMG!

Comment: @user1710120 I'm glad you resolved the issue. You are welcome to mark this answer as correct if you wish.